# Python - Get Contact from Phone Number

Tags: android, python, android-contacts, phone-number, sl4a

Using SL4A and Python, is there an easy way to get a Contact ID from a phone number?

The phone number is from the 'address' field of an SMS.

I am trying to avoid searching through all contacts.

I use `m = droid.smsGetMessageById(id, None).result` to get the SMS message. The result looks like:

> `{u'read': u'1', u'body': u"Hello! Your mobile bill's now ready to view at virginmobile.co.uk/youraccount. We'll collect your Direct Debit of 12.12 on or just after 19th Nov.", u'_id': u'1323', u'date': u'1415372649502', u'address': u'1234567890'}`

The value in the `address` entry is the phone number that sent the SMS.

I want to get a contact ID  using this number, but, if possible, I want to avoid searching all my contacts.

Comment: Please add some inputs and expected outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
def contactFromPhone(phone):

  uri='content://com.android.contacts/data'
  filter='data4 LIKE ?'
  args=['%'+phone+'%']
  columns=['contact_id']

  contacts=droid.queryContent(uri, columns, filter, args).result

  cs=[]
  if len(contacts)>0:
    for c in contacts:
      cs.append(c['contact_id'])

  return cs
```

'phone' is a normalized phone number

returns a list of contact_id

Comment: where do I get more documentation about the same?